# High pitched noise from Shower

Tags: bathroom, shower, noise

I live in an 8 unit co-op.  Recently had the bathroom totally redone.  New pipes and bathtub/shower. My new shower seems fine.  Not long after I got this done I have noticed someone is causing a high pitched sound when they take a shower.  Could the plumbing done in my unit cause someone else to experience this problem?  Could the pressure change in my Unit cause someone else to have pressure problems.  What should I do about it? The noise is very load.

Comment: Is there a maintenance person for the co-op. If so, I would talk to them about the noise first.

Comment: It's unlikely anything you did would have made something in another unit start making noise if your fixtures/pipes aren't making noise. Any number of things could be causing the noise in the other unit.

Answer (score 1):

My tub spout would make an awful squeal when the shower stopper was pulled up (air in the line trying to escape the poorly seating valve). It would change pitch and stop sometimes if I jiggled the lever right. Find the offending unit and ask to replace their tub spout. Tell them why and they will almost certainly agree to it. A change in pressure may get it to stop momentarily. Take a shot in the dark and cycle *your* faucet valves on and off to attempt re-seating the seal of your neighbors' tub spout stopper valve, when you hear it howling. Or be proactive, finding out whose it is and whose job it is to fix it.

[image]

[image]